# how to fetch data from NSMutableArray ObjectAtIndex from integer value?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to fetch data from my NSMutableArray, I am doing this

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
     A_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     A_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"4",@"6",@"2",@"3",@"0",@"5",@"1",@"2",@"4",@"1",@"0",@"2",@"4",@"2",@"0",@"3",nil]
    var_Count_Answer_A   = 0;    // int  
}

-(void)method_Second {
    NSLog(@"%@",[A_array objectAtIndex:var_Count_Answer_A]);    // This line is crashing if I  click button again. First time line works fine but if we click button again and    var_Count_Answer = 2 then it will crash.

    NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[A_array objectAtIndex:var_Count_Answer_A]];   // If I comment on NSLOG then this line will crash
    A = [str1 integerValue];
    NSLog(@"A is %d",A);


    var_Count_Answer_A ++;
}
```

if I try this `NSLog(@"%@",[A_array objectAtIndex:5]); // works fine`

```
NSLog(@"%@",[A_array objectAtIndex:var_Count_Answer_A]);  // var_Count_Answer_A =5; and crash
```

Any Idea or Suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: where is define var_Count_Answer_A

Comment: Are you using ARC? Where are all these iVars defined?

Comment: (not really related to your problem) In your -viewDidLoad, you are calling "A_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];" followed by a "A_array = [NSMutableArray arrrayWithObjects:...]" call. That's not necessary since "[NSMutableArray arrrayWithObjects:...]" allocates and initializes a NSMutableArray for you, filled with the object given to this method

Comment: as @Sunny suggested . Put some crash logs otherwise no one will know whats going on !

Comment: @kirti mali  I defined var_Count_Answer_A .h file int type.

Comment: Error log--> 0x111809b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi  Thread 1: EXC_Bad_Access (code 1, adress = 0xd0000008)

Comment: for defense programming i further more suggest you put:
if (var_Count_Answer_A >= [A_array count]) { return; }
as the very first statement of your -method_Second.
(Funny side effect) You will then see whether or not your counter is invalid, since nothing will be printed at all, if it's invalid

Comment: you need to set property and synthesize of your NS-mutable array and use self.A_array

Comment: @NishaSingh: Mind reading http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html? Will help us and you with better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
A_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4",@"6",@"2",@"3",@"0",@"5",@"1",@"2",@"4",@"1",@"0",@"2",@"4",@"2",@"0",@"3",nil];
```

Instead you used.

```
A_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     A_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"4",@"6",@"2",@"3",@"0",@"5",@"1",@"2",@"4",@"1",@"0",@"2",@"4",@"2",@"0",@"3",nil];
```

As I review Your Project is ARC disable try this Working fine for me.

```
ViewControler.h
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController 
{
    NSMutableArray *A_array;
    int var_Count_Answer_A;
}

ViewControler.m
-(void)viewDidLoad  {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     A_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4",@"6",@"2",@"3",@"0",@"5",@"1",@"2",@"4",@"1",@"0",@"2",@"4",@"2",@"0",@"3",nil];
var_Count_Answer_A   = 0;
     var_Count_Answer_A   = 0;    // int
        }

-(IBAction)method_Second:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"%@",[A_array objectAtIndex:var_Count_Answer_A]);    

     NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[A_array objectAtIndex:var_Count_Answer_A]];   // If I comment on NSLOG then this line will crash
     int A = [str1 integerValue];
     NSLog(@"A is %d",A);

     var_Count_Answer_A++;
        }
```

But As Everyone know at last there must be occur this exception.

```
NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 16 beyond bounds [0 .. 15]'
```

As trying to access array index object that does not exist.
`And if you still have some error then First Enable NSZombie in your project Follow this.`

-> "`Product`" menu, select "`Edit Scheme`", go to the "`YourAp.app`" stage in the left panel, and the "`Arguments`" tab on the right. You can then add `NSZombieEnabled` to the "`Environment Variables`" section and set the value to `YES`.

`And Now Share your Crash Log.`

Comment: this error is showing - symbol stub for: getpid

Comment: Please enable NSZombie as i also updated my answer and share the crash log.

Comment: -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x71c07a0

Comment: @NishaSingh as your project is ARC disable now try my updated code only change one line. `A_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4",@"6",@"2",@"3",@"0",@"5",@"1",@"2",@"4",@"1",@"0",@"2",@"4",@"2",@"0",@"3",nil];`
`

Comment: DownVoter please comment..!

Comment: You are really the great Sir. Superb.... How I did not see that? wowwwwww gr88888........ Thanks alooot.... I will Accpet your answer.

Comment: oh Sorry by mistake I select. I up voted you ok. And also mark right your answer.

Comment: @NishaSingh Keep Coding Good Luck :)

Answer (score 3):

**Your code hurt my eyes**

There are certain coding standards to be followed while writing code in Objective-C. Every language got one. They make code readable and understandable. You can refer to [Cocoa Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) and help yourself writing better looking code.

**Explain Properly**

Without the error message before crash no one can help you. Next time when you post about a crash, also explain the error message you got.

Was it a `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`? If so it is the awesome garbage collector sweeping your array object away. Anyway your code sores my eyes and I am taking the privilege refactoring the code. Maybe it will help you.

**A little bit of refactoring**

```
NSArray *aArray;
- (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     aArray = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"];
     // or use[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"];
     //Why do you need a mutable array while initializing it static?
   }

 - (void)methodSecond
   {
     static int counter = 0;
       if (aArray) {
         if (counter<aArray.count) {
           NSLog(@"A is %u",[[aArray objectAtIndex:counter++]integerValue]);
         } else {
           counter = 0;
           [self methodSecond];
         }
       }
   }
```

**Understand what you are doing**

So a detail explanation of what I guess your problem is:

- You're using [NSArray initWithObjects:] this creates an autoreleased object, and we got no control over its life time. And they get released if they are not referenced immediately after creating, which is probably whats happening your case. In my experience, mutable autoreleased object always sources bad access problems. So it is better to have the object alloc and inited, ie.. [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:] and I observe you are not adding/removing array members in run-time. There is no purpose of having a MutableArray.
- In your code, you're creating two objects. The first array object is allocated and immediately dereferenced  in the next line. Which is probably a mistake.

If you want to know more about auto-released objects. Read [this](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/).

Comment: Thanks alooot... Your code is fantastic. Its working superb, exactly what i wanted... Thanks Alooottt....

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are usimng two different varaibles once check thosetwo.

`var_Count_Answer` and `var_Count_Answer_A`

Comment: Sorry Sir by mistake I forgot to write _A here in my code both are var_Count_Answer_A only.

Comment: this error is showing  -  symbol stub for: getpid

Comment: @ Nisha Singh:your code seems to be good nut some where else you went wrong i think so.

Comment: @Sunny i think prob only some how var_Count_Answer_A release and she access this variable at second Method might be in her project ARC enable. i think so only reason is this.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are using an **auto-released object**.
When you call like:

```
A_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"4",@"6",@"2",@"3",@"0",@"5",@"1",@"2",@"4",@"1",@"0",@"2",@"4",@"2",@"0",@"3",nil]
```

The A_array is an autoreleased object, you can't say when it'll be released. That is why this error occurs.

Solution:

Declare a property for the array like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *A_array;
```

Then modify your methods like:

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
     _A_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"4",@"6",@"2",@"3",@"0",@"5",@"1",@"2",@"4",@"1",@"0",@"2",@"4",@"2",@"0",@"3",nil]
    var_Count_Answer_A   = 0;    // int  
}

-(void)method_Second
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[_A_array objectAtIndex:var_Count_Answer_A])
    NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[_A_array objectAtIndex:var_Count_Answer_A]];
    A = [str1 integerValue];
    NSLog(@"A is %d",A);
    var_Count_Answer_A ++;
}
```